# Team Viewer Install Stuck Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: teamviewer

I downloaded. the deb package and double clicked.  It brought up the Ubuntu Software Center and the orange bar that shows the progress gets to the very end but never finishes.  How do I get it unstuck, installed and verify it installed okay?

Response to Update 2:

```
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ dpkg -l *teamviewer* | grep ii
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ dpkg -l *teamview* | grep ii
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ sudo dpkg purge teamviewer
[sudo] password for halcyon-ideas: 
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

Comment: Please close the Software Center and retry it again like three times. It usually happens that way.

Comment: @George one good reason to set `gdebi` as the default installer for .deb packages.

Comment: Other oddities started to occur so did a fresh install.  Gdebi worked like a charm thanks!  Also installed synaptic which the combination of the two has fixed the issues that seemed to have been caused by the Ubuntu store not installing things correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In `terminal`...

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/teamviewer_i386.deb
```

So, if the installer is on your Desktop...

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/teamviewer_i386.deb
```

In case dpkg indicates missing dependencies, complete the installation by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Update #1:**

In `terminal`...

Show me the output of...

```
dpkg --print-architecture # should say amd64

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures # should say i386
```

**Update #2:**

In `terminal`...

```
dpkg -l *teamview* | grep ii # observe the name that gets returned

sudo dpkg purge name_that_got_returned_from_above # this will uninstall it
```

probably...

```
sudo dpkg purge teamviewer
```

Download and install https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_amd64.deb

**Note:** This install may fail because "on newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7), teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems".

Comment: It indicated missing dependencies so I did the sudo apt-get install -f however, it encountered another error.  Please see below: Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc1:i386
 libc6:i386
 libgpg-error0:i386
 libgcrypt20:i386
 liblzma5:i386
 libpcre3:i386
 libselinux1:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: In `Software & Updates`, Ubuntu Software tab, are all of the repositories checked, and is the "Download from" server set properly? See Update #1 in my answer for further info.

Comment: All of check boxes are checked on the Ubuntu Software tab with the exception of "source code".  Nothing happens when using the dpkg --print-architecture or the dpkg --print-foreign-architectures.  Below is an excerpt form terminal.
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ 
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
halcyon-ideas@Halcyon-Ideas:~$

Comment: It's difficult to read the output of when put into comments. Editing the original question is a better way... just paste them in. Any way, it looks like the two commands give the correct answers... amd64 and i386. So try this... oh... let me put it into Update #2 in my answer... give me a few minutes...

Comment: Added terminal results to question.  Please see "Response to Update 2" .  Nothing is returned when using the dpkg command to find the name.  I used the apt list --installed command and did find "teamviewer" listed.  So plugged that into the purge command and got an error.

Comment: Go ahead and download the 64-bit TV and try and install it and lets see what happens. See my link in Update #2.